# What direct flights connect Brazil or Argentina to South Africa?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, airlines, africa, south-america

I'm curious, what airlines offer direct flights between South America and Africa and what cities do they connect?

Comment: I wish there was a standardized route map available to find direct flights between destinations, if they exist. inter-continental connections are the bane of my existence

Comment: Considering the sizes of the two continents this is a very open question. Can't you narrow it down to a handful of countries? Some people may not feel this is a real travel question and doesn't have one right answer.

Comment: The distance from Sao Paulo to Johannesburg is 7444km the max range of older 747's is 12000km(777-200lr can do about 17000km) and they like to leave a little in the tank just encase which is possibly why you find there aren't a lot of airports with direct flights. However you can certainly get a direct flight from Sao Paulo to Johannesburg.

Comment: I don't think range is really much of an issue. You can see here that from Rio de Janeiro a 747 could fly to any point in Africa http://www.boeing.com/commercial/747family/pf/pf_rc_riodejaneiro.html

Comment: Direct doesn't have to mean nonstop. The SAA flight from Washington DC to JNB pauses in Dakar to refuel and spray insecticide on us all.

Comment: When I asked the question, I meant nonstop, but a list of direct flights would be interesting too.

Comment: Hmm London to Melbourne is about 17000km and I had heard that was the longest direct commercial route in the world. Not sure if that's correct or if anyone currently flies it direct or in what aircraft though...

Comment: I nominated the question to be reopened. The answers so far and an educated guess suggests it is really not that broad. A search of some major airlines (Royal Air Maroc, Ethiopian, Kenya Airways, Egyptair…) only turns up flights between Brazil or South Africa and other places, which suggest that some general insight on how to link the two continents would be valuable. You can't just assume it's broad based on the way airlines work in other parts of the world.

Comment: Besides, there are already some upvoted answers and the question itself has many upvotes so the content is there and is valuable to readers, closing the question only makes it difficult to update or extend it but does nothing to help manage the site.

Answer (score 15):

I don't believe a definite list of flights exist, but here's what I found after a fairly exhaustive search.

- Buenos Aires, Argentina to Cape Town, South Africa on Malaysia Airlines
- Buenos Aires, Argentina to Johannesburg, South Africa on South African Airways
- Sao Paulo, Brazil to Luanda, Angola on TAAG Angola Airlines
- Sao Paulo, Brazil to Johannesburg, South Africa on South African Airways
- Rio de Janeiro, Brazil to Luanda, Angola on TAAG Angola Airlines
- Fortaleza, Brazil to Praia, Cape Verde on TACV

Comment: Malaysia Airlines ceased flying EZE-CPT in February 2011 as part of a restructuring effort.

Answer (score 7):

1. Find a busy city in South America, say São Paulo
2. Find the web site of its airport: [Infraero](http://voos.infraero.gov.br/) (all brazilian airports)
3. Look for a flight from São Paulo on an african company: [Consulte seu voo](http://voos.infraero.gov.br/voos/index.aspx), say South African Airways
4. And you can find direct flights to Johannesburg.

Another way would be to check national airline companies of major destinations: Cairo, Rio de Janeiro, Nairobi, Buenos Aires, ...

I am not aware of a method for finding all direct flights from one continent to another.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to find out direct flights from one city to another city based on flight schedules, use www.routehappy.com .

Example - all direct flights from [Buenos Aires](https://www.routehappy.com/list?utf8=%E2%9C%93&list_search%5Bdeparture_city_name%5D=Buenos%20Aires,%20Argentina&list_search%5Bdeparture_city_id%5D=1029)

Disclaimer: I work for Routehappy